# Switching to other field when the value is null using whereYear Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, builder

I have question with regard to switching on other field when the second field is null using `whereYear`.

Say for example we have this database table

```
+------------+------------+
| field_one  | field_two  |
+------------+------------+
| 2020       | NULL       |
+------------+------------+
```

I want to switch to `field_one` when the value of `field_two` is null. It doesn't work using `orWhere` because `orWhere` switches to field one if the condition is not matched or false. I'm not really sure if `orWhere` is the solution for this.

```
$year = Carbon::now()->year;
$table = DB::table('my_table')
            ->where(function($table) use ($year) {
                $table->whereYear('year', '=', $year)
                      ->orWhereYear('year', '=', $year);
            })->count();
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a raw query combined with `IFNULL()` - `whereYear()` basically applies the MySQL function `YEAR()` to a datetime, and we can do that manually to combine it with `IFNULL()`, which selects the second column if the first one is `NULL`.

```php
$year = Carbon::now()->year;
$table = DB::table('my_table')
            ->whereRaw("YEAR(IFNULL(field_one, field_two)) = ?", [$year])
            ->count();
```

Comment: It does work even without specifying the table name. Thanks Qirel!

Answer (score 0):

I know  this question is old but here is an answer if you want to keep it 100% eloquent :

```
DB::table('my_table')
        ->where(function($query) use ($year) {
            $query->whereYear('field_one', '=', $year)
                  ->whereNotNull('field_one')
                 // OR
                  ->orWhereYear('field_two', '=', $year)
                  ->whereNull('field_one');
        })->count();
```